# Plugin for Jeklly on tagging

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I wrote a simple plugin for Jeklly that basically takes my `site.owner.email` which I defined in `_config.yml` and obfuscate it, then put it on my About page. I have the following code:

**_plugins/obfuscate_email.rb**

```
class ObfuscateEmail < Liquid::Tag
  def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
    @text = text
    super
  end

  def render(context)
    output_array = []
    char_array = @text.split('')
    char_array.each do |char|
    output = "[dot]" if char == '.'
    output = "[at]" if char == '@'
    output = "[plus]" if char == '+'
      if output
        output_array << output
      else
      output_array << char
      end
    end
    output_array.join
  end
  Liquid::Template.register_tag "obfuscate_email", self
end
```

Use it in this case:
`{% obfuscate_email site.owner.email %}`
will give result like this: `site[dot]owner[dot]email`, but I was expecting something like this to return `owner[dot]something[at]gmail[dot]com`

How would I suppose to call this?

Thanks

Comment: @Slartibartfast edited my above post, hope that makes the question clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your plugin into liquid filter like this:

```
module MyFilters
  def obfuscate_email(input)
    # your code here
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(MyFilters)
```

That way this syntax should work:

```
{{site.owner.email | obfuscate_email}}
```

Comment: How do I convert it to Liquid Filter?

Comment: By using `Liquid::Template.register_filter` instead of ``Liquid::Template.register_tag`, as Slartibartfast showed.

Comment: Works Thanks! I'm not sure how this would be different than a normal Jekyll plugin, but it works!